# silverlight 4 OOB application wont work after deployment

Tags: c#, silverlight, iis, com

I have a silverlight 4 application .

And I call the COM Excel by using the following

```
excel = AutomationFactory.CreateObject("Excel.Application");
excel.Visible = true;
```

Everything works as expected when i run it from visual studio. But when i deploy it in my local IIS, it does not come up.

I have also selected "Required elevated trust" in the project.

The problem is after deployment.

If there any IIS setting that I am missing.

Thank you.

Comment: So, do you run as admin on your development machine?

Comment: @Will : I have given "Everyone" permission to the silverlight page and full control and I am deploying it locally ... i.e. IIs on my machine. It is the same as development platform

Comment: could it be that your web server does not accept the mime type for xbap? What kind of server/version is it?

Comment: @slfan : .xbap does list in configured MIME types. I am using IIS 7.0 . whatever comes with windows 7 .. anything else that I can try .. thank you

Comment: I got it working. ... was a silly mistake ... just have to right click and install the OOB application to do that ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

The configuration of the IIS you find here: [Configuring IIS for Silverlight](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/262/configuring-iis-for-silverlight-applications/)

Updated:

The problem could also be that your application has to run out-of-browser, because you use COM components.

Comment: will try that out ... and yes it is configured to run OOB. and it works fine when I run in from VS 2010.

Comment: I got it working. ... was a silly mistake ... just have to right click and install the OOB application to do that ... thank you

Comment: That was my 2nd guess and what I meant with it has to run out-of-browser.